# Best practice to compare if extended object contains values of old object

Tags: java, javabeans

Let's pretend I have object like:

```
FirstName = "A"
LastName = "B"
DateOfBirth = "17"
Age = "1999-06-17"
```

After adding additional fields, my object is

```
FirstName = "A"
LastName = "B"
DateOfBirth = "17"
Age = "1999-06-17"
AddressObject
         {
          AddressType = primary
          Street = "My street"
          Building = 11
         }
```

What is the best solution to compare objects and see that old fields are same and added new reference object Address is not empty in JAVA.

Comment: Concatenate the property values into a string and hash the string.  If two objects have the same hash value for their properties, nothing has changed.

Comment: Seems like 50% of solution, but if Chnaged, because I will deliberately my contact for a example will always change First name but other fields will stay not changed. but yes sounds like good Idea. I can exclude fields I will always chage from string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

If these are Java classes then the fields are fixed pre-runtime. You could check if fields are empty or not in given instances but that's it. If this is some representation like JSON then you need to parse the JSON into an object instance and compare in the same way. You cannot add fields to a class in Java at runtime. (barring weird tricks with class loaders or reflection)

Comment: Oh sorry for made you think that I will use reflection. No I wont. All fields initialize when object created. So they will just null. But the probkem is that there are many of fields in object and compare field by field seems to much writing.